# Thread's join() method won't work for waiting the thead to finish in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, multithreading, authentication, windows-phone-8

I'm doing a SharpBox authenticating for WP8. I searched "wait for a thread to finish" and I got so many answer suggesting using `join()`. So I added it to my code inside of the click handler:

```
 private async void uploadBtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
 {
     System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(getMyToken);
     thread.Start(); // Start a new non-UI thread to handle the request
     thread.Join();

     // The following codes must wait for the result of getMyToken!!!

     // the rest of the authenticating codes here
 }
```

And the `getMyToken` method for the non-UI thread (All the vars below are declared before the constructor so it can be re-used in other method):

```
 public async void getMyToken()
 {
      Debug.WriteLine("GOT IN!");
      config = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox) as DropBoxConfiguration;
      Debug.WriteLine("Done 1st");

      requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, "MY KEY", "MY SECRET");
      Debug.WriteLine("Done 2nd);

      AuthorizationUrl = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxAuthorizationUrl(config, requestToken);
      Debug.WriteLine("Done 3rd");

      Uri requestUri = new Uri(AuthorizationUrl);
      Debug.WriteLine("Done 4th");

      Uri redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost");
      Debug.WriteLine("Done 5th");
}
```

The code below `thread.Join();` just hang and the debugger reaches `GOT IN` only. And if I delete `thread.join();`, the code below `thread.Join();` throws `NullReferenceException` because the non-UI thread has not finished its work yet..

But if I delete all the code below `thread.join();` and `thread.join();` itself, The debugger can reaches `Done 5th`.

I don't know what did I do wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn some basics about async-await. You marked your methods async, but you never used await inside it. Async method without an await is always synchronous. Don't use threads, even if you do, don't start it and call join immediately. you can always call the method synchronously(atleast you can save one thread). Don't block the UI thread. Etc. There are several problems.

Comment: If I bring those `requestToken` from `getMyToken` to the UI-thread in the click handler, it will just hangs there and won't do anything. People says that it should be handled in a non-UI thread, so that's why I created another thread.

Comment: At first, the "rest of the code" which is `await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, redirectUri);` is in the `getMyToken` method, but someone says that it should be handled in UI thread so I decided to get it back to the click handler. That's when the problem happens. You have some advice for this?

Comment: It's a good thing it doesn't work, as that's terrible.  You're trying to block the UI thread.  I'm surprised the OS doesn't pitch you out the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `async` keyword from `getMyToken` and then call it like this from your `Tap` handler:

```
await Task.Run(() => getMyToken());
```

This will run the DropBox code on a background thread (presumably the DropBox API is doing network calls and might take a long time) but keep the UI responsive until the API returns.

Comment: Looks like my code has problems so it won't shows the web authenticate. Anyway, your solution did what I wanted to, finally it runs in the right order